# Kafka Connect in Docker container: Connector not added

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to get a simple Kafka Connect container running. I did try the [Confluent Connect Tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/installation/docker/docs/installation/connect-avro-jdbc.html), but have a slightly different setup (no docker machine, no schema registry).

For the time being, I'm working with a Docker compose setup containing Zookeeper and Kafka.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
      - ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000
      - ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT=2
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092
      - 9094:9094
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      # setup :9092 for access inside the docker network, 9094 for outside (ie host)
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka:9094
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS=10
```

That works fine for different uses, so I don't expect this to be a problem.

Now I'm starting a Kafka Connect container which connects fine to Kafka. I use the following command which is adapted from the Connect Tutorial:

```
docker run -d \
  --name=kafka-connect-test \
  --net=kafka-connect_default \
  --expose 28083 \
  -p 28083:28083 \
  -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 \
  -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=28083 \
  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="quickstart-test" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-test-config" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-test-offsets" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-test-status" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
  -e CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG \
  -e CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java/kafka,/etc/kafka-connect/jars \
  -v /tmp/quickstart/file:/tmp/quickstart \
  -v /tmp/quickstart/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars \
  confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
```

The most notable difference is that I'm using the `StringConverter`, because I'd like to use `kafkacat` to insert test data.

The container starts up fine and is running and reachable on all the exposed endpoints I tried.
 Since I didn't add any connectors, I query the available ones:

`localhost:28083/connector-plugins`:

```
[
  {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "5.4.0-ccs"
  },
  {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "5.4.0-ccs"
  },
  {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1"
  },
  {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1"
  },
  {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1"
  }
]
```

So for now it would be enough for me to create a file sink that writes data from a topic to a file. I POST to `localhost:28083/connectors`

```
{ "name": "file-sink", 
 "config": { 
     "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
     "tasks.max": 1, 
     "file": "/test.sink.txt",
     "topics": "test-topic"
 }
}
```

and receive `201 - Created`.

However, when querying that endpoint with `GET`, I get an empty array as a response. Trying around, I can also change the `connector.class` to `FileStreamSinkConnector` or just `FileStreamSink` and will still get a `201` (without a connector being added).

What am I doing wrong?

And why am I getting "success" responses when something obviously went wrong?

Comment: By the way, file sink inside a container seems like a bad idea. I'd suggest using Minio and the S3 Connector if you really want to have something "production like"

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah I know, these merely represent my very first steps with Connect ever. Didn't get the MySQL sample from the Quick Start working so I thought I'd go even more basic.

Comment: Yeah, I rarely use the JDBC ones. Landoop Connect tutorials are good. This blog post as well https://blog.minio.io/journaling-kafka-messages-with-s3-connector-and-minio-83651a51045d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter" \
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter" \
```

The *internal* converters are just that - internal, and since Apache Kafka release 2.0, [deprecated](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-174+-+Deprecate+and+remove+internal+converter+configs+in+WorkerConfig). If you check the Kafka Connect worker log after creating the connector you'll see this:

```
ERROR Found configuration for connector 'connector-file-sink' in wrong format: class java.lang.String (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore)
```

That's because Kafka Connect uses Kafka itself as a state store, and when you create a connector it stores it on a Kafka topic (`CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC`). This defaults to JSON and it looks like Kafka Connect does not like that being changed (and indeed, there is no reason to ever change it).

If you run the same Docker command as before, but *without* the two `CONNECT_INTERNAL_` converter lines, you'll find that things work just fine.

Here's the connector being created (I'm using a `PUT` instead of a `POST` because it's idempotent and easier for re-running):

```
curl -i -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:28083/connectors/file-sink/config \
    -d '{
     "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
     "tasks.max": 1,
     "file": "/test.sink.txt",
     "topics": "test-topic"
}'
```

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 09:16:04 GMT
Location: http://localhost:28083/connectors/file-sink
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 211
Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)

{"name":"file-sink","config":{"connector.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector","tasks.max":"1","file":"/test.sink.txt","topics":"test-topic","name":"file-sink"},"tasks":[],"type":"sink"}%
```

Now check that it's running (with a bit of bash stuff to reformat it nicely):

```
curl -s "http://localhost:28083/connectors?expand=info&expand=status" | \
       jq '. | to_entries[] | [ .value.info.type, .key, .value.status.connector.state,.value.status.tasks[].state,.value.info.config."connector.class"]|join(":|:")' | \
       column -s : -t| sed 's/\"//g'| sort
sink  |  file-sink  |  RUNNING  |  RUNNING  | org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector
```

Send some data to the topic:

```
➜ kafkacat -b localhost:9094 -t test-topic -P -K:
1:foo
2:bar
```

Observe data in the file written to by Kafka Connect:

```
➜ docker exec -t kafka-connect-test bash -c 'tail -f /test.sink.txt'
foo
bar
```

---

BTW regarding:

> The most notable difference is that I'm using the `StringConverter`, because I'd like to use kafkacat to insert test data.

Note that you can set converters per-connector as part of the configuration; setting StringConverter at the *worker* (i.e. global) level is probably not a good idea as you would rarely use this, certainly for values.

---

For more on Kafka Connect check out:

- [From Zero to Hero with Kafka Connect](https://noti.st/rmoff/Jcugyt/from-zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect)
- [Kafka Connect Deep Dive – Converters and Serialization Explained](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/)

Comment: Can you "create" a connector at `http://localhost:28083/connectors/<connector-name>/config` (with the PUT)? Don't you need to POST to `/connectors` first?

Comment: You can use `PUT` on its own